# how to skip an error prone query and jump to next one in python

Tags: python, sql, teradata

I have 10 rows in a dataframe and each row having a single query. I am looping through each row of the dataframe and try to execute the query. Among those 10 rows there were some query issues. I want to skip those queries and execute next query.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: please post the code that you have tried thus far

Comment: df = DataFrame(cur.fetchall())
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(row[1])
    fnl_qry = " select count(*) from "+ row[1] +" where col1 = "+ row[2] + ";"
    print(fnl_qry)
    cur.execute(fnl_qry)
    rec_cnt = cur.fetchone()
    output = fnl_qry + "|" + rec_cnt
    print(output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would doing a try except pass during each iteration work?

Im not sure what query issues you are facing, could you elaborate?

```
try:

except:
      pass
```

Comment: df = DataFrame(cur.fetchall()) <br/>
for index, row in df.iterrows(): <br/>
    #print(row[1]) <br/>
    fnl_qry = " select count(*) from "+ row[1] +" where col1 = "+ row[2] + ";" <br/>
    print(fnl_qry) <br/>
    cur.execute(fnl_qry) <br/>
    rec_cnt = cur.fetchone() <br/>
    output = fnl_qry + "|" + rec_cnt <br/>
    print(output) <br/>

Comment: your code worked ( except: pass).. Thanks for your help on this